# Como Adaptar Formulario WindowsForms a cualquier resolucion de panttalla, C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Quisiera adaptar el formulario con sus respecivos botones a cualquier resolucion de monitor. Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow te recomiendo que le eches un ojo a como hacer una [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Edita tu pregunta y comparte con nosotros lo que has intentado hacer hasta el momento para que tengamos un punto de partida. A simple vista sin saber lo que has intentado parece que lo que buscas es usar ´Dock´ y ´Anchor´